# Does an attack from a chaotic-aligned character break regeneration/chaotic?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alignment, damage-types, regeneration

I am DMing an adventure where the players can fight an arbiter inevitable. The inevitable is listed as having regeneration 2/chaotic. The book says that the type after the slash is the damage type needed to stop regeneration, but I'm not sure what counts as doing 'chaotic damage'.

Would an attack by a PC with a chaotic alignment count as doing chaotic damage and break the regeneration?

What options are available for a Level 2 party to break the regeneration, if the answer to the above question is 'no'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the main question:

### No, the attack from a chaotic character does not count as chaotic

A chaotic character wielding a weapon does not makes this weapon chaotic. From an in-universe point of view, a second level character does not change the nature of the weapon they wield.

> An *Anarchic* weapon is infused with the power of chaos. It makes the
>   weapon chaotically aligned and thus bypasses the corresponding damage
>   reduction

Anarchic is a +2 enchantment. Without it, or an appropriate ability, the weapon wielded stays an inert chunk of metal/wood/whathaveyou (and thus does not inflict chaos aligned damage, therefore won't stop an inevitable regeneration).

Ways for a second level party to gain chaotic damage:

- *Anarchic Strike (minor)* from a 1st level Warpriest

(Not found any other yet, parsed spells with [chaos] descriptor)

Comment: Maybe they're just not meant to be able to kill the arbiter permanently, just stun it.

Comment: [align weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/align-weapon/) is the apocryphal answer, but isn't available until level 3 afaik (outside of wands and scrolls). My next thought would be Summon Monster but none of the default choices are Chaotic Outsiders

Comment: - Sacred Weapon ability of the Champion of the Faith archetype for the Warpriest.
 - Smite Impudence ability of the Insinuator archetype for the Antipaladin.

Comment: Actually I think I may have mixed up regeneration with DR here. Sacred Weapon should still work but Smite Impudence only bypasses DR and not regeneration.

Comment: While Summon Monster might not have creatures with the Chaotic subtype, the Summoner's eidolon does have it if it is Chaotic.